# Check if input string is parenthesis completed

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a function, that would check for a matching parentheses.
For example, if the given string is "(1+1))" it would print false otherwise it's true.
However, in my code it's printing false no matter what the case is.

```
bool isMatched(char pran[]) {
    bool completetd = true;
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; pran[i] != '\0'; i++) {

        if (pran[i] == '('){
            count++;
        }
        else {
            // It is a closing parenthesis 
            count--;
        }
        if (count < 0) {
            // there are more Closing parenthesis  
            completetd = false;
            break;
        }
    
    // If count is not zero, there are more opening parenthesis 
    if (count != 0) {
        completetd = false;
    }
    }
    return completetd;
}


int main() {

    char arr[] = "((1+a))";

    if (isMatched(arr)) {
        printf("TRUE \n");
    }
    else {
        printf("FALSE \n");
    }


    return 0;
}
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Your first `else` statement will actually be executed for *any* character other than `'('`, so `count` will decrement for every other character rather than just `')'`. Rather than an `else`, you should have that be a separate statement such as `if (pran[i] == ')')`

Comment: Thank you soo much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding a
`printf("got 1 (!\n");` next to `count++;`
and a
`printf("got 1 )!\n");` next to `count--;`,
you get:

```
Got 1 (!
Got 1 (!
Got 1 )!
Got 1 )!
Got 1 )!
FALSE
```

This shows that you have a validation problem with your checking logic

As pointed-out in the comments, replace your `else` with `else if (pran[i] == ')') {` will fix that part for you.
But the real problem lies with your last validation.
Take it out of the `for` loop. It sets the value to `false` *as soon* as you detect a parenthesis.

Thus, take this:

```c
    // If count is not zero, there are more opening parenthesis 
    if (count != 0) {
        printf("Count: %d\n",count);
        completetd = false;
    }
    }
```

and make it this:

```c
    }
    // If count is not zero, there are more opening parenthesis 
    if (count != 0) {
        printf("Count: %d\n",count);
        completetd = false;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. this solved it. Sorry my bad it shouldn't be in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this not sure if this is what you are looking for.

```c
bool isMatched(char pran[]) {
    int open = 0;
    int close = 0;

    for (int i = 0; pran[i] != '\0'; i++) {

        if (pran[i] == '('){
            open++;
        }
        
        if (pran[i] == ')'){
            close++;
        }
    }
    // Check if both match
    if(open == close){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}


int main() {

    char arr[] = "((1+a))";

    if (isMatched(arr)) {
        printf("TRUE \n");
    }
    else {
        printf("FALSE \n");
    }


    return 0;
}
```